# Restrict Google Places API to specific country

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to restrict autocomplete to a specific country, i.e. USA. How can I do this? I've tried the following below, by passing the variable options as a parameter into the initialization function:

```
   <script>
    var autocomplete = {};
    var autocompletesWraps = ['test', 'test2'];

    var test_form = { street_number: 'short_name', route: 'long_name', locality: 'long_name', administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name', country: 'long_name', postal_code: 'short_name' };
    var test2_form = { street_number: 'short_name', route: 'long_name', locality: 'long_name', administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name', country: 'long_name', postal_code: 'short_name' };

    function initialize() {

        var options = {
            types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
        };

        $.each(autocompletesWraps, function(index, name) {

            if($('#'+name).length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            autocomplete[name] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#'+name+' .autocomplete')[0], { types: ['geocode'] }, options);

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[name], 'place_changed', function() {

                var place = autocomplete[name].getPlace();
                var form = eval(name+'_form');

                for (var component in form) {
                    $('#'+name+' .'+component).val('');
                    $('#'+name+' .'+component).attr('disabled', false);
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                    if (typeof form[addressType] !== 'undefined') {
                        var val = place.address_components[i][form[addressType]];
                        $('#'+name+' .'+addressType).val(val);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not passing the `options` correctly.  `Autocomplete` takes two arguments, and you're passing three.

Specifically, in this line:

```
autocomplete[name] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    $('#'+name+' .autocomplete')[0], { types: ['geocode'] }, options);
```

your `options` parameter is unused, because you've passed `{ types: ['geocode'] }` as the options.

So remove the extra argument:

```
var options = {
    types: ['geocode'],  // or '(cities)' if that's what you want?
    componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
};
autocomplete[name] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    $('#'+name+' .autocomplete')[0], options);
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize it only accepted two, but makes sense given that my last two were basically equivalent to one another.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to integrate the Google Address API with only **United Kingdom** address. Please find the below address :

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript>
var autocomplete;
function initialize() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (document.getElementById('txtpostcode')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(
            {'country': ['uk']});
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: your script type missing double qoutes at the end